# How to add TF on a object whose coordinate is already detected by PCL

Tags: c++, ros, point-cloud-library

The coordinate of the object is already detected by PCL. For this purpose, I am using a Kinect v2 camera. I have written that code in C++ and I am working in ROS platform. Now I want to add TF on the object detected by the Kinect using PCL library.

Extra notes: My objective is to grab a moving object on a conveyor belt by a robot.
Any ideas would be a great help for me.

Comment: You should write a TF broadcaster, see [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20broadcaster%20%28C%2B%2B%29). The data to publish should come from your PCL software.

Comment: Hopefully, I can write TF for Kinect and Robot. But confused about the alignment with the object.
If I make TF for my Kinect camera will it also impose/act as a TF for the object also? I think I have to align the Robot with respect to the object. Like wherever I put the object, Robot's manipulator will come to this line where it will stand face to face of the object.